# Error de PHP: Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, mysql, insert, rutas

Hola mi problema es que estoy intentando hacer un insert en mysql, tomando los datos del siguiente formulario:

Se que es un problema de que estoy poniendo la ruta mal o de permisos, pero no encuentro donde he metido la pata.
Para ello uso el archivo "añadirPedido.php" que adjunto a continuación

El archivo php esta en la misma carpeta que el archivo del formulario.

```
<body>
<h1>Formulario de Compra</h1>
<div class="f">
    <form method="get" action="añadirPedido.php">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dni">Introduzca su dni</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dni" placeholder="DNI">

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombre">Introduzca su nombre</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="nombre">

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="apellidos">Introduzca sus apellidos</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellidos" placeholder="apellidos">

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="direccion">Introduzca su dirección</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion" placeholder="direccion">

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="tfno">Introduzca su teléfono</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tfno" placeholder="tfno">

        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="comfort">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="comfort">¿Desea la versión confort?(Esto aumentara un 20% el importe de la casa)</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

```
    <?php

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","rootroot","paginacasas");
    if($link){
            $dni = $_POST['dni'];
            $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
            $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
            $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
            $tfno = $_POST['tfno'];
            $comfort = $_POST['comfort'];
                if($comfort){
                    $bool=s;
                }else{
                    $bool=n;
                }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Pedidos (dni, nombre,apellidos, direccion,tfno,comfort) VALUES ("."'".$dni."'".", "."'".$nombre."'".", "."'".$apellidos."'".", "."'".$direccion."'".", "."'".$tfno."'".", "."'".$comfort."'".")";

        $resultado=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        if ($resultado) {
            echo "Pedido insertado correctamente";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
        }


        $link->close();

        }

?>
```

Comment: Pues te diría que tienes problemas con "añadirPedido.php" esa ñ la quitaría para los nombres de archivo dejalo como anadirPedido.php a ver. Saludos.

Comment: Era Justo eso, muchísimas gracias me has salvado la vida jajajaj.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Creo que la respuesta es simple, sino me equivoco. Estas mandando el formulario por GET y estas buscando si te llego algo por POST, prueba eso y comentas.

Otra cosa, te aconsejo siempre usar el metodo POST, ya que con get, los datos que introduces, se ven reflejados en la url, y utiliza consultas preparadas siempre, evitaras injections.

Te dejo un trozo de código de como recojo yo los datos en php de un formulario.

```
if (isset($_POST['usuario'])){
    $usuario=strip_tags(trim($_POST['usuario']));
}
```

Comment: Eso estaba mal, pero el error era por la ñ del nombre del archivo.

Comment: Muchas gracias igualmente jajajaj